# Prevent user of selecting same values on select html

Tags: html

I have two selects with the same values

eg:

```
<select id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can I prevent user not to choose the same values on both boxes?

I am populating the select values with PHP from a database.

EDIT:

I arrived on this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrr9ngj8/1/)

But it needs improvement when changing a value already selected.

Comment: You should add using which technique? Javascript, jquery?

Comment: Why not use a select multiple? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Comment: I didn`t want to.. but it`s an idea.. because there are like 25 options.. and to hold ctrl and choose.. i dont find it practical

Comment: So, u can go with checkbox list, no need to hold down `ctrl`

Comment: @Vikrant what do you mean? i just want if he selects mercedes on the first one.. he cant select the same on the second.. like.. it hides the option mercedes on the second

Comment: They are good ideas.. but I was looking to do with selects and hiding whats already choosen..

Comment: are u okay with `jquery` to be used for the same?

Comment: Yes. no problem at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(function(){
  $('select').change(function() {
  $current=$(this);
  $("select").not($current).children("option[value='"+$current.val()+"']").attr('disabled', "disabled");
  });
 });
});
```

I arrived on what I wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/zrr9ngj8/2/

Answer (score 0):

First of all HTML and CSS are not designed for something like that.

Said that,maybe you can hack CSS to do something similar but
since `<option>` inside both `<select>` haven't any relationship (Child-Parent, Sibling...) you can not use CSS pseudo selector (`:checked`)to disable options like that:

(this code wont work for this case but it would remove duplicates if the options will be in the same `<select>` because they would be sibling)

```
[value="volvo"]:checked + [value="volvo"] {display: none;}
```

Comment: They are not static values, as I said, I am populating the options with php from a database.

Comment: The client side code you send is totally static. When user will check any option in browser, you need to **notice** it in the server side (through Javascript, AJAX or whatever) or change the client side code (as I was saying).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#1').change(function() {
  $("#2").not($(this)).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']")
    .prop("disabled", true)
    .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h43b3337/16/)

You can remove the siblings part if you don't want to re-enable previously selected options.